# ¿Cómo comprobar la existencia de páginas web a partir de un script lanzado en Google Cloud?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, docker, google-cloud-platform

Estoy siguendio [este tutorial](https://dev.to/googlecloud/using-headless-chrome-with-cloud-run-3fdp) para aprender a usar headless Chrome en la nube de Google en orden. El objetivo final es volver a ejecutar un script para ir a las páginas y ver si existen.

Hasta que no tengo Docker installado intenté:

```
mikempc3@instance-1:~$ gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/my_service
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) HTTPError 403: Insufficient Permission
```

El archivo que quiero llevar a cabo es:

```
import selenium

from collections import defaultdict
import json

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

import time

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_red = pd.read_csv("tickers_september_2017_updated.csv")

tradable = []
for ticker in df_red['Ticker']:
    print(ticker)
    location = "https://www.etoro.com/markets/" + ticker.lower() 
    driver.get(location) # vamaos al ticker
    time.sleep(2)
    current_url = driver.current_url # almacenamos la dirección donde realmente nos lleva
    if current_url == location: # Si sigue siendo el mismo, significa que el teletipo es negociable.
        tradable.append(ticker)
```

#Actualizacion

Las páginas que no existen no devuelven un error 404 sino que redirigen a la página de login. Por ejemplo:

```
ticker:  MT
no page but request=  <Response [200]>
```

¿Cómo puedo averiguar con request que la página no existe y que soy redirigido?

El script que utilicé para descubrir esto es:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from collections import defaultdict
import json

import time

import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Programs\chromedriver.exe")

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/antoi/Downloads/tickers_september_2017_updated.csv')    

tradable = []
print(len(df['Ticker']))
for ticker in df['Ticker']:
    print("ticker: ", ticker)
    location = "https://www.etoro.com/markets/" + ticker.lower()
    try:
        request = requests.get(location)
        driver.get(location)
        time.sleep(2)
        current_url = driver.current_url
        if current_url == location:
            tradable.append(ticker)
        else:
            print("no page but request= ", request)
    except ConnectionError:
        print('Ticker isn\'t tradable')
    else:
        tradable.append(ticker)
```

Comment: Para visitar páginas con el único propósito de ver si existen, yo no me complicaría con Selenium ni Chorme headless. Un simple uso de la biblioteca `requests` y después examinar que el status code sea 200 sería suficiente.

Comment: @abulafia Desafortunadamente la solicitud no devuelve un 404 cuando la página no existe porque la página es redirigida automáticamente a otra página. ¿Sabría cómo detectar esto y aún así prescindir del selenio?

Comment: Sí, puedes pasarle a `request.get()` el parámetro `allow_redirects=False`. De ese modo `requests` no seguirá la redirección, y en `status_code` tendrás el código de redirección en vez del 200.

Comment: @abulafia Es raro, porque para [https://www.etoro.com/markets/mt](https://www.etoro.com/markets/mt), que no existe, todavía tengo una respuesta de 200. Tal vez es porque parece estar cargando algo antes de redirigirnos a otra cosa

Comment: Es que esa pagina no redirige, responde un 200 Ok y un html valido, pero ese html contiene un iframe y sospecho que el contenido del iframe se carga dinamicamente mediante js. De ser asi me temo que hacerlo sin selenium sea compicado.